# Masking Email address along with domain using regex

Tags: java

The requirement is as below:

```
Input: rajani@gmail.com
Output: r****i@*****.com
```

I tried below two regex's but I could not able to mask the gmail(domain name). Kindly help me on this.

```
String masked_email_Address2=email_Address.replaceAll("(?<=.{1}).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");
```

Output received as `r****i@gmail.com`

I searched in stack overflow on this, I got the below regex but it does not produce the correct result:

```
String masked_email_Address1=email_Address.replaceAll("\\b(\\w)[^@]+@\\S+(\\.[^\\s.]+)", "$1***@****$2");
```

Output received as: `r***@****.com` -- One star(*) is missed between R&@.

Comment: What is your exact problem? That there are only three asterisks (*) instead of four or that the last character before the @ sign is replaced by an asterisk as well?

Comment: Dear dpr, as mentioned, i would like to mask the gmail (domain) as well by using the below regex. String masked_email_Address2=email_Address.replaceAll("(?<=.{1}).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");

Comment: Is your requirement to comeup with a single regex? You could simply replace the part before the @ first and the second part afterwards. Perhaps provide more examples to know what your expected input and output is.

Comment: what is the desired output for `r@my-domain.com` or `rr@localhost`?

Comment: Hi Dpr, Thanks for the response!.. please find the desired output: r@********.com and r*@********

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments will be shown initially. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I started out trying to do this with a one-liner using `String#replaceAll` as you were doing, but then gave up, because variable length lookbehinds are not supported, and I could not come up with a pattern which did not use them.

Instead, try just using a format pattern matcher:

```
String email = "rajani@gmail.com";
String pattern = "([^@]+)@(.*)\\.(.*)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(email);
if (m.find( )) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    sb.append(m.group(1).charAt(0));
    sb.append(m.group(1).substring(1).replaceAll(".", "*"));
    sb.append("@");
    sb.append(m.group(2).replaceAll(".", "*"));
    sb.append(".").append(m.group(3));
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

[image]

### Demo

This may look like a lot of code to do a relatively small formatting job on an email address.  If you like, you may put this code into utility method, and then you can still get the masking effect with a single line of code, when you call the method.

Comment: Dear Tim,But i required last character of the email address. Like : r****i@*****.com

Comment: Dear Tim, I have added the one more line: sb.append(m.group(1).charAt(index-1));. So the desired output received. Thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
String masked_email_Address2=email_Address.replaceAll("(.)?[^@]*([^@])@\\S+(\\.[^\\s.]+)?", "$1****$2@****$3");
```

This will work as long as your address is longer than 1 character long.

Comment: But here you have hard-coded the number of asterisks.  I'm not sure if the OP wants that.

Comment: You're right, but given this little information in the question, this requirement is/was not clear to me.

Comment: I agree, and I personally have nothing wrong with a fixed number of asterisks.  Although, one could argue that having the same number of characters might remind the user that it's really his email address.

Comment: and provides additional information about the "hidden" address. :-)

Comment: Yes.. the asterisks are hard-coded which does not produce the exact result if the user entered the email address as "udayakumarr@gmail.com" The output should be: u********r@*****.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int idx = email_Address.indexOf('@');
 String part1 = email_Address.substring(1, idx-1).replaceAll(".", "\\*");
 String part2 = email_Address.substring(idx + 1, email_Address.lastIndexOf('.')).replaceAll(".", "\\*");

 String masked_email_Address1=email_Address.replaceAll("^(\\S)[^@]+(\\S)@.*(\\..*)", "$1"+ part1 + "$2@" + part2 + "$3");
```

Comment: It does not work... I have given the input as "udayakumarr@gmail.com" and the ouput received as same as input. Please help on this.

Comment: @UdayaKumar updated the regex, one * had to be escaped while pasting here  :(

Comment: but the **** are hard coded . so, it does not produce the exact characters while masking. output received as u****r@****.com but it should be u********r@****.com

Comment: @UdayaKumar modified the answer to incorporate your comment

Comment: Dear Froxovi,, It would be much helpful if you explain the replace method (\\S)[^@]+(\\S)@.*(\\..*)

Comment: Double backslashes used to escape backslash.

(\\S) -> any non-space character
[^@]+ -> any character other than '@', occurring one or more time
(\\S) -> any non-space character
@    -> matches @
.*    -> matches any character zero or more occurrences.
(\\..*)->matches a dot('.') followed by any character zero or more occurrences.